# how can I successfuly sanitise taken photo in ionic 4 using capacitor plugin

Tags: camera, ionic4, capacitor, angular-dom-sanitizer

ionic 4 capacitor camera plugin after taking a picture and then sanitizing but still getting this error:

`SafeValue must use [property]=binding: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4UHuRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABgEaAAUAAAABAAAAVgEbAAUAAAABAAAAXgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAITAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAIcuocAAcAAAgMAAAAZgAAEOQAAAEsAAAAAQAAASwAAAABHOoAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....`

here is my method in .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins, CameraResultType, CameraSource} from '@capacitor/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const { Camera } = Plugins;

  constructor(
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }


 async takePicture() {

  const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 100,
    allowEditing: false,
    resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
    source: CameraSource.Camera
  });

  this.takenImg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(image.dataUrl);

}
```

and in .html file:
    `<ion-item>
            <span (click)="takePicture()">Camera</span>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-img [src]="takenImg" alt=""></ion-img>
          </ion-item>`

Answer (score 0):

I use a standard `<img>` tag for this rather than the `<ion-img>` tag and I don't need to sanitize:

```html
<img [src]="image.dataUrl"/>
```